# Recive POST data by http server

Tags: java, android, http, server

I have simple http server on android from Android Samples. I like this server, so I also want to recive POST data from browser. How can I recive it with standart things (without external libraries) ? I try to recive it like GET, but js console show connection error.

```
private void handle(Socket socket) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    PrintStream output = null;
    try {
        String route = null;

        // Read HTTP headers and parse out the route.
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while (!TextUtils.isEmpty(line = reader.readLine())) {
            if (line.startsWith("GET /")) {
                int start = line.indexOf('/') + 1;
                int end = line.indexOf(' ', start);
                route = line.substring(start, end);
                break;
            }
        }

        // Output stream that we send the response to
        output = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        // Prepare the content to send.
        if (null == route) {
            writeServerError(output);
            return;
        }
        byte[] bytes = loadContent(route);
        if (null == bytes) {
            writeServerError(output);
            return;
        }

        // Send out the content.
        output.println("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
        output.println("Content-Type: " + detectMimeType(route));
        output.println("Content-Length: " + bytes.length);
        output.println();
        output.write(bytes);
        output.flush();
    } finally {
        if (null != output) {
            output.close();
        }
        if (null != reader) {
            reader.close();
        }
    }
}
```

[full code](https://developer.android.com/samples/PermissionRequest/src/com.example.android.permissionrequest/SimpleWebServer.html)

Comment: can you post the structure of the json or data you are trying to parse?

Comment: @GastónSaillén it will be just text data without json

Comment: `I have simple http server on android from Android Samples. ` Please povide a link so we can see what you are working with.

Comment: @greenapps hey, look to full code link.

Answer (score 0):

In general the http request is a text fragment. The type of the request is indicated in the text. So in a GET request the example you provide first finds the "GET" string. Then parses the get request. The same should be done for POST. First identify the "POST" then parse the rest of the request.

Comment: Nope. I did it. Cant see anything. Only POST with headers. Then error on JS console.

Comment: Perhaps you should post what you tried. Any error in the JS console is related with the response you return.